# Why does Pyglet not run correctly from the Python IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle, pyglet

After installing the [Pyglet](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/index.html) library on my windows 10 machine, I deiced to test if it was working correctly by running a shortened version of the code provided from *[Writing a pyglet application](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/quickstart.html)*:

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=640, height=320, caption='window')
pyglet.app.run()
```

However, when the window was finally displayed, this is what was shown:

[image]

To make sure this wasn't an OS problem, I went back and re-read the pyglet requirements. [It stated that it would work with Windows XP and greater](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/overview):

> - **Windows XP or later**
> - Mac OS X 10.3 or later
> - Linux, with the following libraries (most recent distributions will
>     have these in a default installation):
>
>   ```
>   OpenGL and GLX
>   GDK 2.0+ or PIL (required for loading images other than PNG and BMP)
>   Pulseaudio or OpenAL (required for playing audio)
>   ```

The problem seemed to be platform specific because Pyglet worked on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). Finally, after thinking about for a bit, I decied to try running the code from the command line since I was currently running it from the Python IDLE. Sure enough, the code ran and the window was displayed correctly:

[image]

I then realized that this was the only difference I had made when running the code on Linux; I had used the command line. Although I cannot confirm this with absolute certainty, this seems to be a problem created simply from running the code in Python's IDLE.

Has anyone else encountered this behavior. Is this a known problem? If so, what's causing it?

Comment: Strange, is the Python IDLE running in some sort of virtual env? Can't it access windows screen geometry correctly? (what happens if you start the IDLE in a larger window size context?)

Comment: @Torxed Nope. No virtual envs. I tried increasing the IDLE window size as well, but no change. Although I'm not exactly sure why, the problem seems to be that somehow the IDLE is interfering with how Pyglet initializes it's window. The strange part is that the IDLE works fine with other graphics libraries such as Pygame or Tkinter.

Comment: I meant that the IDLE somehow internally sets up a virtual env (with a screensize of 80x60 terminal size). Anyway, might be because they both some how share the same GL context. Seeing as the IDLE probably isn't built upon any framework but instead raw GL. Try fiddling around with a custom context: http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/context.html#contexts-and-configs

Comment: @Torxed Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that.

Comment: @Torxed IDLE uses tkinter, which interfaces to tcl/tk.  It has nothing to do with GL unless tk does.

Comment: Christian, by default, IDLE runs your code in a separate process.  So it mostly should not interfere with what your code does.  (Some exceptions are listed in the IDLE doc.)  I installed pyglet with 3.7.0a1 on my windows machine, and ran the first two lines above in IDLE's shell.  A 640x320 box is displayed with the title line, but there is no separator line or black field.  The X does not work.  I closed IDLE and reran 3.7 from the console and got the same thing.  Clicking X brought up a 'Python has stopped working'  box.  So on my Window 10, IDLE is not the problem.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Okay, thanks. That's Interesting. Perhaps I'm just not installing it correctly. I've tried using `pip` and installing from the zip (`python setup.py install`).  It works fine for me everytime when I run it from the command line. I'll keep searching and pop back in if I find anything.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I see. Seeing as I never installed tcl/tk or compiled Python with it, i figured it was strange if it managed to run it.

Comment: @Torxed The PSF python.org installer for Windows installes tcl/tk by default.  If not installed, tkinter, IDLE, and turtle do not run.  Linux systems often have tcl/tk installed.  In not, one must install from the distributor repository.  Apple comes with a buggy tcl/tk.  To use tkinter, etc, one should add a newer and better version.

Comment: @ChristianDean Since you have pyglet running from the console and I do not, it is more likely that my install is not good.  There could be a Windows specific interference between tkinter  and pyglet when a tkinter window has the focus.  Does the pyglet code run from the console while the IDLE is running?  (This will not be the same, as the console gets the focus as soon as you type into it.)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for explaining, actually appreciate it. I use Windows+Python like 3 hours a month maybe and sit on linux 99% of my time. Usually I never bother running the IDLE because it's just as quick to just run a script on Linux :) But it's good to know these things!

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Hey man, sorry for the late reply. I had went to bed. To answer your question though, yes it does. The code executed from the console still ran fine.